# An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made error when trying to authenticate to ADFS

Tags: ssl, react-native, dynamics-crm-2011, adfs, tls1.2

I'm building an app in react-native and when I try to authenticate to ADFS, i keep getting this error: "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." I tried adding these lines to my info.plist (react-native on an iphone 6 emulator) but it still occurs: Not sure why this is happening. Does anyone have any insight as to why this is happening? Thanks!

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> <dict> <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> <true/> </dict>
```

Comment: There isnt enough SSL/TLS specific diagnostic info here to comment as to what may be happening. if there are means to take a network trace or enable SSL/TLS diags, please do. Is the AD FS internet accessible? When you attempt to access the AD FS, are you doing so from a corporate network where you access AD FS direct or via WAP servers (ask your IT if not sure) . If AD FS is configured using certs that chain to public root, test the SSL/TLS strength using an external test service like https://www.ssllabs.com/. If full cert chain is not returned in server hello this might cause issues.

Comment: The ADFS is internet accessible. I'm developing on company's wifi network so it is via WAP servers. You can check the test results by submiting: adfs.issi.com

Comment: This is AD FS 2.x. So no WAP. Its using AD FS Proxy. Only TLS 1.0 and below is supported by your server based on ssllabs.com. Hope the app is able to use TLS 1.0. Cert chain appears to come down OK. You need to get client side debug logs if possible on SSL/TLS use. We cant say more based on info so far.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help so far. There is an npm JavaScript library called request that lets you specify SSL version so I will try to use that to authenticate. Unfortunately, the debugger I use react-native-debugger doesn't seem to capture any network requests. I'll try using chrome console tomorrow. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Bummer. Request and Request-promise are libraries that aren't supported in react-native because they depend on modules in the node.js library. I wonder if there's any other way I can work around this issue....

Comment: Out of interest what protocol is your app supposed to use after tls/ssl works? Is it ws federation or saml2? Your existing adfs won't do anything else.

Comment: I'm not sure I am connecting to a ms dynamics 2011 server though. I believe it's saml. My plan is to use a 3rd party to authenticate like miniOrange or auth0.

Comment: In that case what role does adfs play here. Can you please state intention and correct any irrelevant tags please?

Comment: Details of any libraries used for auth on app side would help too

Comment: I was trying to use Jason Lattimer's library to authenticate to adfs to authenticate to CRM dynamics 2011. You can find it here https://gist.github.com/jlattimer/bfeffb02d3efd159d0af . Adfs authenticates user to the CRM system for external and internal users.

Comment: His blog entry can be found here : https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/jasonlattimersblog/archive/2014/04/22/soap-authentication-to-crm-on-premise-adfs-using-javascript . I feel that the tags are all relevant. What don't you think is relevant?

Comment: Well you mentioned auth0 and didn't seem entirely sure of auth flow. Wsfederation would be in use if dynamics and adfs are in the picture. Not saml2

Comment: The blog is talking of using wstrust to the username mixed endpoint

Comment: Honestly I'm lost as to wstrust and wsfederation and saml2.

Comment: As long as you are trying to do what the blog says you are fine. Adfs can work here. You just need to get more details as to why ssl/tls issues are present. You need to get past that before any discussion on wstrust etc can happen

Comment: I believe it's because our company is using tls1.0 as you stated earlier so if they upgrade hopefully that error will go away.

Comment: Tls1.0 is supported on your adfs. Rather than do arbitrary upgrades a little more troubleshooting would be more appropriate.

Comment: What I'm saying is my mobile client can't make tls1.0 calls it only supports 1.2 and above. Also, I have no idea how to get more information on what's going on with the ssl connection error.

Comment: How would I troubleshoot that error?

Comment: Ok in that case you are better off configuring adfs servers to support tls 1.2. They can coexist and frankly the momentum is to move away from tls 1.0 anyway

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/245030/how-to-restrict-the-use-of-certain-cryptographic-algorithms-and-protoc has details of how to configure windows to support tls 1.2

Comment: Thanks for your advice ill keep you posted.

Comment: After setting up a test adfs server using TLS 1.2, i'm still getting the same error. Any clues?

Comment: Sorry I can't say much more without a clear error.

Comment: Finally got the adfs server on TLS 1.2. Now i'm getting the following error: "<s:Body><s:Fault><s:Code><s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value><s:Subcode><s:Value xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:FailedAuthentication</s:Value></s:Subcode></s:Code><s:Reason><s:Text xml:lang="en-US">ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized.</s:Text></s:Reason></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>"

Comment: the beginning of the _respone begins with: " <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action><a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:374b39b8-122f-43ad-95bc-95d059b580c6</a:RelatesTo></s:Header>"

Comment: That's a better error. You've got past tls. Who sends soap fault? Is that from adfs?

Comment: I think it's from ADFS. it comes from the getHeaderOnPremise function in jason lattimer's library.

Comment: Make sure the password is encoded correctly if it has special characters. Looks like the credentials weren't validated. So I suspect password wasn't sent correctly. This assumes soap response is from adfs.

Comment: My password doesn't have special characters. I'm going to look at adfs event log tomorrow and I'll let you know what I see.

Comment: ADFS tracing debug log throws this strange error: "ID4063: LogonUser failed for the <domain_name> user. Ensure that the user has a valid Windows account.-Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password" Any clues what this means? I'm stumped because I can log in to the CRM deployment no problem from a regular web browser.